# MVC 4 Web Api routing not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, url-routing, asp.net-web-api

In my mvc4 project, I have the following routing defined in Global.asax:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

             routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

and my view(Home/Index) is something like below :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

                    function find() {
                    var id = $('#prodId').val();
                       $.getJSON("api/Products/"+id,
                        function (data) {
                            alert(data.Name);
                         })
                    .fail(
                        function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                            alert('error');
                        });
                    }    
    </javascript>

    <body>
             <div> 
                <label for="prodId">ID:</label> 
                <input type="text" id="prodId" size="5"/> 
                <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="findAll();" /> 
                <p id="product" /> 
            </div> 
    </body>
```

it works fine when im using : `http://localhost:1868/` 
but not when im try it like : `http://localhost:1868/Home/Index`

is there anything im doing wrong ? or missing something ?

any help appreciable ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're using `api/Products/` as the url, whereas it needs to be `/api/Products`. Without the leading `/` character, the browser assumes the path is relative from the current path, (e.g. `/Home/Index/api/Products`), which is why it works from `http://localhost:1868/`. The `/` character tells the browser to make the call relative to the host, not the current path.

Comment: hey Matthew , can i use api/{controller}/{action}/{id} in "DefaultApi" route ? when i try, it's not working ...